# Pyqt slider not updating

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qslider

I have created a GUI in Qt Designer with a horizontal slider inside a grid layout within a tab widget. Here is the code from the GUI.py file:

```
self.horizontalSlider = QtGui.QSlider(self.tab)
self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalSlider"))
self.horizontalSlider.setRange(0.1,0.4)
self.horizontalSlider.setValue(0.4)
self.horizontalSlider.setTickInterval(0.05)
self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider, 3, 1, 1, 1)
```

I have set up a connection for the release signal in my main code:

```
self.horizontalSlider.sliderReleased.connect(self.SmoothSelected)
```

At runtime, the slider remains at the start position and I am unable to move it. I tested its value with:

```
 print(self.horizontalSlider.value())
```

but get '0', not '0.4' as I have set the value to be. The other widgets in the tab work fine. Have I forgotten something simple like enabling it or something?

Answer (score 4):

Documentation states:

> The slider is the classic widget for controlling a bounded value. It
>   lets the user move a slider handle along a horizontal or vertical
>   groove and translates the handle's position into an **integer** value
>   within the legal range.

Consequently, `setRange`, `setValue` and `setTickInterval` accept only *int* as a argument. That is - you can only move slider by *int* values.

The workaround is either converting int value from `QSlider` to float by multiplying it to .01 (or other value), or implementing your own `QDoubleSlider` like in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dennis-tra/994a65d6165a328d4eabaadbaedac2cc).